# No Windows Azure Web Sites publish option in VS 2012 website publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to help a colleague setup their development environment to deploy to an azure website. Both of us have Visual Studio 2012 update 5, Azure SDK 2.6 and Web Deploy 3.6 installed but my colleague does not see the option I see (see screenshot 1), they only see what you can see in screenshot 2. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

[image: My Screen]

[image: Colleague's Screen]

Comment: Why are you using a 6 year old copy of Visual Studio? Is there a feature you're using there that's not available in VS 2017 Community? You're missing out on the Azure integration like big time, not to mention you'll run into these types of problems and outside of calling MS Support there's not much to do about..

Comment: There are quite a few Azure legacy features that we are using that are not supported or have been deprecated in later additions of the SDK. These have not been updated/scoped for change so we are stuck with what we have got unfortunately

Comment: It looks like the SDK installation is broken on the 2nd machine. I would try to reinstall and if that doesn't work (which is the most probable outcome), just give up and import the publish profile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO6hP.jpg